# Late 2006 MacBook doesn't turn on (fan spinning but no chime)

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My Late 2006 MacBook (MACBOOK2,1) doesn't boot anymore after I turned it off in ElementaryOS.

Symptoms :

- Fan spinning
- Sleep LED is on
- Screen not turning on
- No chime

And here are the specs :

- CPU : Intel CORE 2 Duo 2.0GHz
- GPU : Intel GMA950 (No GPU acceleration at all in my patched El Capitan install)
- Model Identifier : MacBook2,1 (the Late 2006 one, not Mid 2007)
- OSes : Patched OS X El Capitan and ElementaryOS

I only have my main Linux Desktop and a Snow Leopard USB Installer.

I've tried Resetting the PRAM/NVRAM and SMC without success. I've also tried inserting the ORIGINAL RAM that came with this Mac, still, without success. I've removed the HDD and plugged it into my main Linux Desktop and, everything was fine (the linux partition and OS X partition were mounted successfully).

I really think this is a hardware issue, but don't know how to fix it.

PS: This issue happened after another issue I had, the computer would turn on, with the chime, but the screen stays grey. I got this fixed by resetting the NVRAM/PRAM and booted into ElementaryOS. I turned it off and got this problem.

Comment: What have you done so far to diagnose/troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: I've tried Resetting the PRAM/NVRAM and SMC without success. I've also tried inserting the ORIGINAL RAM that came with this mac, still, without success. I've removed the HDD and plug it into my main Linux Desktop and, everything was fine (the linux partition and OS X partition were mounted successfully). I really think this is a hardware issue, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I've checked the CPU and GPU, both are looking fine

Comment: I had similar symptoms with a different Mac recently. Can you boot it from an Install CD/DVD? Not sure if this one supports USB booting but if it does and you have a bootable USB macOS installer that would be worth a try as well. If those fail I would think that lovely old MacBook may have run down the curtain and joined the choir invisible.

Comment: No, I can't boot it from an Install USB and I don't have an Install CD/DVD. So I think it's bricked. :(

Comment: It *SOUNDS* likely but without trying to boot from other media, specifically an installer I would be hesitant to say that definitevely.

Comment: You mean, by hitting the "c" key or "alt/option" key?

Comment: Yes that is how you start the process but I would want to see how far the boot and install process gets before failing.My, now dead, MBA would seem to boot from an installer but never finished and just hung on a black screen for hours and then overnight. If you boot to the installer but there is nothing to install to it might just be the HD or HD controller.

Comment: It just cannot turn on. Thats doesn't work :(

Comment: @SteveChambers Do you have a solution ?

Comment: My solution to my (similar but not exactly) was a new Mac. That no one else has chimed in tells us that either I am correct and nobody has anything to add. Or no one has seen similar issues. After a while the only thing you can do is take it in to an Apple repair tech and see what they say.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for helping me, Ibfound an answer : reset manually the nvram/pram by disconnecting the pram/nvram battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Hi, v64isgood_vitali64 (or just Vitali64) here

---

I've found an answer !

I taked apart my Mac and disconnected the NV/PRAM battery, waited a few minutes, reconnected it back and reassembled my macbook.

**Conclusion : IT WORKS !**

So I booted into the MacOSX Install USB and setted the date by  using the terminal bc it was set to **31 December 2000** which prevented El Capitan to work.

For those who want to know how to do that, [HERE](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Core+2+Duo+PRAM+Battery+Replacement/529) is an article from iFixIt that will explain how to achieve that on the particular model that I have.

I think that the Firmware had tried to apply the settings I had in OS X, into Linux, which corrupted the PRAM/NVRAM, and then just stayed in the black screen when turning on since...

I hope you're doing well and that this may fix your issue.